# How can I switch between 2 on_release on kivy?

Tags: python-3.x, function, kivy, kivy-language, alternate

I want to know how I do to give the 1 kivy button two features, for example a pause and unpause button, where when I click pause, it changes the value from on_release to another function, and when you click again, it goes back to the first, and so on.

I tried this:

```
======= Main.py =======

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout

class Main(BoxLayout):
    pass

class test(App):
    def build(self):
        return Main()

    def Pause(self):
        Main().ids.pause_unpause.on_release = self.Unpause
        print('Paused')

    def Unpause(self):
        Main().ids.pause_unpause.on_release = self.Pause
        print('Unpaused')


test().run()

======= test.kv =======

<Main>:
    Button:
        id: pause_unpause
        on_release: app.Pause()
```

But he does not switch functions, can someone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two problems with your code:

1. Calls to `Main()` in your methods create a new instance of `Main` that is not the `Main` that appears in your GUI. So calling any methods on those new instances will have no effect on your GUI.
2. Changing the `on_release` binding of a Button during the processing of the `on_release` event will probably cause unexpected results.

I suggest just using a single `on_release` method that keeps track of the paused/unpaused state:

```
class test(App):
    is_paused = BooleanProperty(False)

    def build(self):
        return Main()

    def Pause_Unpause(self):
        self.is_paused = not self.is_paused
        if self.is_paused:
            print('Paused')
        else:
            print('Unpaused')
```

And the corresponding `kv`:

```
<Main>:
    Button:
        id: pause_unpause
        on_release: app.Pause_Unpause()
```

Comment: I don't know how it will help me with the question of a single button switching between two functions, but thanks for your attention.

Comment: In the `Pause_Unpause()` method you can call one or the other of the two functions in place of the `print()` calls.

Comment: If you must actually change the `on_release` method, you might try delaying the change till after the `on_release` processing is complete using `Clock.schedule_once()`.